# Почему корабль не двигается, при этом никакой ошибки не выходит

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders") #title
icon = pygame.image.load("python games/ufo.png") #icon
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

playerImg = pygame.image.load("python games/player.png") #player
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.3
            if event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.3
        if event.type ==  pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Извиняюсь за вставку всего кода, но т.к. я не знаю где именно ошибка, я прошу вас отметить, почему корабль(player) не двигается с помощью стрелок на клавиатуре влево и вправо по оси x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ветке

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

вместо

```
if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
```

должно бытъ

```
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
```

точно так же как в ветке

```
if event.type ==  pygame.KEYUP:
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло

Comment: @Astro тогда стоит принять ответ, чтобы было видно, что есть ответ